# O que é uma subclasse virtual no Python e quais suas vantagens?

Tags: python, python-3.x, característica-linguagem

No Python podemos implementar uma class abstrata a partir do módulo [`abc`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html) e uma das formas é a classe herdando de `abc.ABC`:

```py
from abc import ABC

class AbstractClass(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def method(self):
        ...
```

A partir desta classe podemos definir uma subclasse a partir da herança direta:

```py
class Subclass(AbstractClass):
    def method(self):
        return "Metodo da subclasse"
```

Ou definindo uma subclasse virtual a partir de [`AbstractClass.register`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html#abc.ABCMeta.register):

```py
class VirtualSubclass:
    def method(self):
        return "Metodo da subclasse virtual"

AbstractClass.register(VirtualSubclass)
```

Ao verificar a partir da função `issubclass` ambas as classes satisfarão a condição:

```py
print(issubclass(Subclass, AbstractClass))  # True
print(issubclass(VirtualSubclass, AbstractClass))  # True
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/Z4esFO)</sup>

Então qual é a diferença entre implementar uma subclasse a partir da herança ou virtualmente a partir do `register`? Quando utilizar a subclasse virtual?

Comment: Tá aí uma coisa que sinto falta em Java: classes herdarem métodos estáticos. Aposto que tem também uma sobrescrita de funções estáticas aí

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado Não sei se entendi o que quis dizer xD

Comment: o método `register` pertence à `abc.ABCMeta`. E ele passa a ser de `AbstractClass` no momento que você faz `AbstractClass(abc.ABC)`.

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado Se não me engano cada classe armazena um conjunto de referências às subclasses que possui. A função `issubclass` verifica se a classe faz parte deste conjunto. Neste caso, a função `register` *apenas* adicionaria a referência à classe nesse conjunto, sem passar pela construção da herança.

Comment: Pelo o que entendi, a subclasse virtual é um meio de dizer que a classe B atende ao contrato definido por A mesmo enquanto B não for A.

Comment: Com classes residentes em seu próprio código não vai haver diferenças. Porém  Se tiver que usar uma classe externa ao seu código, não relacionada a nenhuma classe sua, existente em um pacote de terceiros e o uso dessa classe necessita que se atenda um contrato(interface implícita), de forma que não possa alterar o código então use o `register()` para registrá-la como subclasse virtual e contornar todos esses empecilhos.

Comment: @AugustoVasques Mas se Python não se importa com o tipo e a classe atende ao contrato esperado, qual a razão de registrá-la?

Comment: A linguagem não se importa mas se estiver usando, por exemplo, um design pattern de estratégia e método onde se faz a injeção de dependência exige que classe passada seja especificamente subclasse de determinado tipo ai faz a diferença.

Comment: A discussao estava indo num rumo bom - escrevi a resposta sem ler os comentários aqui, e acho que cobri os dois lados da conversa.  :-) Comentem lá.

Comment: Então - até sexta, quando respondi, não via nenhum caso prático possível - mas hoje usei, e para um "motivo nobre" - provavelmente vou completar a resposta com esse casos depois:
https://github.com/jsbueno/terminedia/blob/484f163cec1e5f74ba8afb9c9b4d26f8705b353b/terminedia/image.py#L339

Comment: TL;DR:  usei o virtualsubclassing numa classe que vai ser um proxy para objetos da hierarquia da "super classe virtual" - e a lógica contida nos proxies em si é diferente das classes que são "proxiadas". Só que os lugares que vão receber esses proxies tem que "percebe-los" como sendo daquela hierarquia.

Comment: Aumentei a resposta agora, explicando melhor esse uso que fiz do recurso.

Comment: Por "coincidência" tem um artigo escrito na semana passada falando sobre isso:  https://www.hillelwayne.com/post/negatypes (estou lendo agora)

Comment: @jsbueno "How is this useful? No idea" haha sinceridade é tudo :D

Comment: Interessante é que o autor escreve mais ou menos o mesmo que eu sobre "collections.abc não terem se tornado tão populares quanto previsto".

Comment: (e na verdade, achar "iterables que não são strings" em particular é bem útil sim, em Python - acho que vou deixar na minha malinha de utilidades)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**TL;DR:** - *atualização* - A principal motivação para criação dessa funcionalidade da linguagem (não a chamada a `.register`, e sim, todo o conceito e mecanismo de "virtual subclassing") quase certamente foi poder registrar classes built-in em código nativo como `dict` e `list` como sendo instâncias dos tipos mais genéricos `collections.abc.Mapping` e `collections.abc.Sequence` (e outros tipos compatíveis). O uso desse mecanismo para classes criadas pelo usuário tem utilidade limitada, como está em detalhes abaixo:

## O feio

A resposta mais simples é: você praticamente nunca vai precisar!

Mas se estiver em um projeto que use o static type hinting com MyPy, pode ser que precise - (e aí, provavelmente vai descobrir que nem tudo são flores ao aumentar a complexidade,  e sua opção, apesar de lógica e a coisa certa não vai funcionar, por que tem coisas mal-feitas nesse caminho aí)

Vamos por partes:

O que implementar uma classe `MinhaCLasse` como uma subclasse virtual de outra `ClasseBase` faz é que, quando em algum ponto no  código, seu, ou de qualquer pessoa usando a sua  `MinhaClasse` é uma instância da  `ClasseBase`, com `issubclass(MinhaClasse, ClasseBase)` retorne `True`.

Então, indo pra um exemplo mais concreto - você cria uma classe que se comporta como uma sequência de Python - implementa por dentro `__getitem__`, `__len__`,  e outras coisas, mas não herda direto nem de `list`, nem de `collections.abc.Sequence`.  Aí você
Isso faz, por exemplo, que se você fosse usar sua classe com uma biblioteca que vá usar "sequencias" de Python. Se o seu time que escreveu esse outro código, e vocês combinaram de sempre testar se um objeto é passado testando `isinstance(obj, collections.abc.Sequence)`, legal - sua chamada vai funcionar, e a junção do seu código com o restante do código do seu time vai funcionar direitinho.

Só que - quantas vezes você já testou se um objeto que vai usar como uma sequência é uma sequência usando isso?  No mundo real, são raras bibliotecas que vão checar se seu parâmetro é uma sequência mesmo usando essa comparação - na prática, seu objeto vai ser plugado num `for` do outro lado, e, se ele não responder direito ao protocolo de "iterable", acontece uma exceção - e pronto, todos ficam felizes. :-)

Isso é - você executa isso aqui:

```
...
class MinhaSeq:
   ...

collections.abc.Sequence.register(MinhaSeq)
...

def qualquer_funcao():
    items = MinhaSeq(...)

    biblioteca_x.funcao_y(items)
```

E, se lá do outro lado, na biblioteca_x, a pessoa prestar cuidar disso, o código poderia estar assim:

```
def funcao_y(obj):
    for item in obj:
        funcao_z(item)
```

Daí, se por acaso, sua `MinhaSeq` não funcionasse como uma sequência ou iterável, 
a linha que tem o `for` iria causar um `TypeError`.

Agora, se lá na biblioteca_x eles "pensaram nisso", o código poderia estar assim:

```py
import collections.abc

def funcao_y(obj):
    if not isinstance(obj, collections.abc.Iterable):
         raise TypeError("funcao_y precisa receber um iterável")
    for item in obj:
        funcao_z(item)
```

Parabéns - agora o TypeError acontece exatamente uma linha antes! 
E - a biblioteca_x só vai funcionar pra quem ou herdar de uma
sequencia oficial do Python, ou lembrar de chamar o "register".
Ou seja - do lado da biblioteca_x, ela não facilitou o uso para
terceiros, e não ganhou *nada* com essa checagem.

(e você tem uma checagem a mais de "isinstance", que se for num
laço apertado pode dar diferença de performance, embora
essa seja uma situação rara em código Python (isso é: uma
única chamada a isinstance ter impacto na performance de um trecho de código))

## o correto

Agora, sim, com a PEP 484, e checagem estática, a biblioteca_x poderia ter o código assim:

```py
import typing as T

def funcao_y(obj: T.Iterable[T.Any]):
    for item in obj:
        funcao_z(item)
```

Observe que nesse caso a biblioteca_x consegue ajudar o usuário  que está preocupado em fazer chamadas com a tipagem correta num projeto grande: o projeto vai incluir a execução do "mypy" em tempo de teste/q.a. e se a chamada no seu código passar um objeto que não seja um "Iterable" isso vai ser acusado 
*antes* do código estar em execução ou produção. E, se, por outro lado,
quem for usar a biblioteca_x não estiver preocupado com essa checagem, não vai estar checando o projeto dele com "[mypy](http://www.mypy-lang.org)"  e vai só fazer a chamada  - que vai funcionar como no primeiro caso acima, sem nenhum código a mais em tempo de execução.

Daí vem o problema com a "virtual subclass": ela **não** vai funcionar nesse caso!
Por que o "mypy" (e outras ferraments similares), não tem como descobrir que você vai chamar o "collections.abc...register" para sua classe na análise estática: ele vai acusar erro na sua chamada da mesma forma.

---

Só para dar um exemplo bem real de quando digo que a "bibitoeca_x" não vai fazer o teste com o isinstance: não é uma anedota - isso não acontece no mundo real - não acontece nem na biblioteca padrão do Python. O encoder de JSON, por exemplo, exige instâncias reais de `dict` e `list` (ou subclassses diretas) para funcionar, e não vai funcionar com `collections.abc.Sequence. Essa semana mesmo teve uma pergunta com alta complexidade no SOen sobre isso, envolvendo usuários com reputação altissima,  e assuntos complexos (como "metaclasses") - e descobrindo bugs na própria implementação padrão do Python: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58031309/108205  (disclaimer: eu estava envolvido na questão e a minha foi a resposta aceita).

---

## (continuando o correto): O que fazer então?

bom, você quer usar alguma verificação de tipagem no Python e fazer as coisas direito do ponto de vista de OO? Então o certo é lembrar que quando o mecanismo do "register" e o virtualsubclassing foi criado, ainda não se tinha pensado na checagem de tipos opcional estática do Python que está ganhando popularidade hoje em dia. O que aconteceria no caso acima, é que em vez de se preocupar em registrar `MinhaSeq` como uma subclasse virtual de `collections.abc.Sequence`, você avisaria com as recomendações da PEP 484 e o módulo Typing que a sua classe respeita a interface `typing.Sequence`.

O problema? É que código Python tipado pra funcionar com o MyPY fica chato de escrever. Por exemplo, se você já declarou a classe `MinhaSeq` sem ser compatível, pela sua herança, com o tipo de sequencia, não pode simplesmente fazer um "=" declarando que agora ela é compatível -  ou seja, isso aqui:
(**TL;DR:** o exemplo abaixo é a forma recomendada em Python modermo
de se criar outras classes que apresentem uma interface entendível
pelo MyPy -- ou seja, quando se está preocupado formalmente com a tipagem
no projeto):

```py
import collections.abc
import typing as T

class MinhaSeq(collections.abc.Sequence[T.Any]):
    ...
```

Funciona - mas não é, obviamente equivalente a chamar o `.register` depois que a classe foi criada. O mais parecido seria usar o `typing.cast` - O "typing.cast" é algo que não faz nada em tempo de execução - devolve o mesmíssimo objeto com que foi chamado - mas passa informação para o checador estático, no caso o mypy, sobre o tipo do objeto retornado. O problema?? O mapeador estático já vai ter aprendido sobre o `MinhaSeq` e não deixa vocẽ alterar o tipo dela depois da declaração - então o retorno do cast, que ele vai entender que é um tipo "Sequence" tem que ser para um nome parecido, mas não o mesmo:

```py
import collections.abc
import typing as T

class _MinhaSeq:
    ...

MinhaSeq = T.cast(T.Type[T.Sequence[T.Any]], _MinhaSeq)
```

E aqui, você estaria pronto pra chamar a `funcao_x(obj: T.Iterable[T.Any]):` passando instâncias de `MinhaSeq`

## O divertido

Apesar de não ter uso prático - mesmo em código super-pedante quanto a tipagem, o interessante das classes virtuais é justamente o "conceito". Pode ser que a ideia volte com mais força daqui há alguns anos (se o "mypy" prestar a mesma atenção na chamada ao "register" que ele presta na chamada ao "typing.cast" por exemplo, a coisa já funcionaria)

Por baixo dos panos, são mecanismos para deixar super-classes responder de forma programática as chamadas de `isinstance` e `issubclass` que estão em jogo - o méto "register" das classes ABC é só uma forma das classes ABC anotarem como é que seus métodos especiais `__subclasscheck__` e `__subclasshook__` são usados -  e é possível sim ter algum projeto que faça um uso legal e com aplicações práticas disso. Mas, como está definida hoje, seria díficil usar as subclasses virtuais num projeto com aplicação prática além de provas de conceito.

## Um caso de uso

Como "exceção para confirmar a regra", durante o último final de semana fui implementar uma funcionalidade em que "virtual subclassing" pareceu prover uma funcionalidade interessante. Eu não teria lembrado desse recurso se não tivesse interagido com essa pergunta - e teria simplesmente usado uma
subclasse.

Há esse projeto livre que estou desenvolvendo - uma biblioteca para desenhos e artes com unicode no terminal - https://github.com/jsbueno/terminedia - Nele, eu tenho uma hierarquia de classes que começa com "Shape" e provê algumas classes especializadas para conter dados gráficos e textuais (por exemplo, uma das classes carrega um arquivo de imagem binário, e mantém os dados internos como uma imagem 
do PIL, uma outra mantém os dados como strings, e tem um mapa de cores 
que funciona como uma paleta: cada caractere pode representar uma cor distinta, etc...).

Todas as classes "Shape" tem em comum que os seus dados são lidos e modificados através dos métodos `__getitem__`  e `__setitem__` - e eu queria prover uma classe de "view" que permitisse escolher uma área menor dentro de um Shape - por exemplo, o retângulo entre as posições (5,5) e (15,10) - e poder alterar dados nessa view como se fosse uma "Shape" - mas o conteúdo da posiçao "0,0" da view iria alterar de forma transparente o conteúdo da original, na posição "5, 5". E assim por diante para qualquer operação gráfica na view: ela apresenta os mesmos métodos e atributos que uma "Shape", mas os dados internos são os da instância original, e todo
o endereçamento é feito só dentro da região de interesse (ROI).

A lógica para uma view dessas é bem simples - ela tem que se preocupar em prover alguns poucos atributos, e acessar de forma transparente todos os outros atributos da instância original. Em Python isso é possível customizando-se o método `__getattribute__` de uma classe, com cuidado.
Então não faz sentido eu ter que ter toda a lógica das Shape na ShapeView, mesmo de forma herdada - (e seria herdada se eu não estivesse usando o virtualsubclassing - isso não consumiria recursos "a mais"). A ShapeView só tem que se "preocupar" em fazer as transformações necessárias nas coordenadas para seu papel de proxi.

Bom, acontece que no restante do projeto, há alguns pontos em que um objeto do tipo "Shape" é esperado.  Como o ShapeView - sendo um proxy para uma Shape - pode fazer tudo o que uma Shape pode, faz sentido ele poder "dizer que é uma Shape, mesmo sem herdar diretamente de uma". E aí que o virtualsubclassing faz exatamente o que seria interessante: o código que verifica a classe com `isinstance(data, Shape)` vai achar que é uma shape. E  mesmo que dentro do projeto isso só aconteça em poucos lugares, com o virtualsubclassing, eu posso incentivar esse pattern para os usuários da bilbliteca - vai continuar funcionando.

O que eu precisei fazer? Primeiro, a classe base "Shape" tem que se tornar uma classe que permite o registro de subclasses virtuais. Isso pode ser feito simplesmente herdando de `abc.ABC` da bilblioteca padrão. E veja que interessante, exatamente a Shape base tinha alguns métodos "abstratos" - que precisam ser overriden pelas subclasses, mas eu não tinha me dado ao trabalho de herdade de `abc.ABC` só por conta disso - como o foco do projeto  (pelo menos no momento), não é estar 100% de acordo com todas as boas práticas de OO, eu simplesmente tinha um `raise NotImplementedError` nesses métodos que precisam ser re-escritos na subclasse. O `@abstractmethod` do módulo `abc` de Python faz pouco mais que isso, então não estava usando. Mas já que eu ia usar a base `ABC` para o virtualsubclassing, não tem por que não usar o  decorador `@abstractmethod` nos 3 lugares em que ele faz sentido.

Um outro ponto qe é legal notar é que, então eu precisava chamar `Shape.register(ShapeView)`  para "ativar" o virtualsubclassing. E, como qualquer callable em Python que receba um callable como único argumento, isso pode ser feito com a sintaxe de decorator - ou seja, o registro da subclasse virtual pôde ser feito assim:

```py
@Shape.register
class ShapeView:
    ...
```

https://github.com/jsbueno/terminedia/blob/140c934da66c0186e52741cbb0dacfa6bc16f0b7/terminedia/image.py#L351

(nota: a chamada `.register` funciona como um decorator por que devolve o argumento original - se ela retornasse `None`, isso não funcionaria - na documentação tem uma nota que na versão 3.3 do Python se deram conta disso e mudaram pra funcionar).

Bom - aí, por fim, pra por água na fervura - eu estava empolgado que todo o conteúdo da classe `ShapeView` tinha ficado mínimo - ela só precisava customizar o acesso a atributos, implementar `__setitem__`, `__getitem__` além de width, height e size  para funcionar como um Shape que faz bem mais coisas -- e me dei conta de com está a implementação, eu precisei replicar nele os namespaces com os métodos de desenho em si - aí não ficou mais tão distante assim de uma "Shape". Então - por esse lado - o ShapeView teve que reimplementar muita coisa do Shape - o virtualsubclassing não trouxe tantos ganhos assim. Mas por outro lado, um ShapeView pode estar associado a qualquer das outras subclasses de Shape - e prover acesso transparente a atributos como `PixelClass` - talvez  para isso funcionar direito, eu acabaria tendo que fazer *todas* as shapes terem que ter as funcionalidades que estão na "ShapeView" - ou  criar subclasses dinâmicas, cada vez que um shapeview fosse criado. - então talvez o saldo do virtualsubclassing ainda seja bastante positivo.

Disclaimer: pelo tamanho do texto usado só pra explicar o caso de uso concreto, dá pra perceber que virtualsubclassing não é uma funcionalidade que se vá usar toda hora.

Comment: Só comentando que já li a resposta, mas ainda não consegui analisá-la por completo, até porque parecer ter muito conteúdo para extrair dela. Já ganhou o meu voto.

Comment: No exemplo que eu citei, strategy pattern, então não é caso de uso. Eu gostaria de saber a respeito desse proxy(deixei a estrela no git) da classe `Shape` sobre a classe `ShapeView`, pergunto porque quero aprender, não seria o caso de usar um padrão de adaptador, adapter pattern, ao invés de um proxy em vista do que foi colocado nessa resposta.

Comment: Bom - primeiro, esse é um projeto de hobby, "céu azul" - em que meu objetivo é (1) ter APIs que permitam criar desenhos e gráficos com unicode no terminal (e em breve outros backends), e (2) deixar essas apis o mais sucintas e intuitivas possíveis para usuários externos. 'boas práticas' e ' patterns' são adotados a medida que me ocorrem no desenvolvimento.
A ShapeView permite acesso a um subconjunto dos dados de imagem de um objeto associado, expondo os mesmos métodos de desenho e etc... e faz isso a partir de um "slice" do objeto original, sem cópia de dados.

Comment: eu ainda não tenho certeza se manter a shapeview em uma hierarquia separada das Shapes é um preciosismo desnecessário, e se ela não poderia apenas ser uma subclasse de 'Shape". Uma refatoração por um mixin ontem a noite deixou ela ainda mais parecida - mas, mesmo que seja uma subclasse de Shape, ela continuaria atuando como um proxy para os dados da Shape associada - isso parece estar certo. Não é o caso de "Adapter" por que quem vai usar a shapeview vai usar a _mesma_ interface que existe em uma Shape (AFAIK, "Adapter" é, grosso modo, uma forma de traduzir uma interface pra outra)

Comment: Quanto ao exemplo que você ctou - "strategy pattern" - sim, pode ser um caso de uso - mas num projeto bem diferente, e menos usado em Python por conta do dinamismo da linguagem.